# invalid types ‘unsigned char[int]’ for array subscript

Tags: c++, c, arrays, types, crc

I'm working on trying to create a CRC using data bytes, and I have written this function:

```cpp
u16 crcGenerate(unsigned char bytes, int len){
u16 crc = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    crc = crc16__computeByteAnsi(crc, bytes[i]); }
    return crc;
}
```

I keep getting the above error whenever this function is called, and I'm not quite sure how to fix it, or even what's wrong.

To avoid bloating this question, I've included the other primary .h and .cpp files that are referenced.

[This is the Command header file (cmgCOM.h)](http://pastie.org/9371836#70-74,78-83)

[This is where the CRCs are computed (crc16.cpp)](http://pastie.org/9371841#11,24)

[This is the primary Command file (cmgCOM.cpp)](http://pastie.org/9371833#14,33)

I really appreciate any help that I can get; if there's any more information that needs to be provided, let me know. I'm not very familiar with C/C++, and I don't know what's causing this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a `*`. You want `unsigned char *bytes`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you intended `bytes` to be an array of unsigned char but you only decalred it as a single unsigned char value.

```
u16 crcGenerate(unsigned char bytes[], int len){
```